# Anything like Mathf.Ceil which understands magnitude of a number whether +/-?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ceil

I need to round to the next biggest magnitude. So 6.66 rounds to 7, but -6.66 rounds to -7.

At the moment I'm doing:

```
int result = Math.Ceil(num);
if(num < 0)
   result -= 1;
```

I'm in the middle of a 2k*2k*2k nested loop, so saving an if/subtract could really help.

Comment: @leppie, sounds like Mathf used in Unity3D, but OP should definitely be more specific... http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.html

Comment: Oops, sorry is that not standard? (Newish to C# and coding in Unity3D). So substitute whatever the standard C# Ceil() is.

Comment: Nope.. In standard C# there's `Math` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "Round Away from Zero" in [this blog post](http://www.jackleitch.net/2010/06/adventures-in-net-rounding-part-2-exotic-rounding-algorithms/):

```
public static int RoundAwayFromZero(decimal value)
{
    return value >= 0 ? (int)Math.Ceiling(value) : (int)Math.Floor(value);
}
```

Comment: Where did the other Answer go: (Math.Round(num,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)??

Comment: Thanks, marked it as correct as it's exactly what I requested. Interestingly, on a loop of 125 million iterations:                  num >= 0 ? (int)Math.Ceiling(num) : (int)Math.Floor(num); //5521 ms                             Math.Round(num, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 4007 ms

Comment: MidpointRounding only applies to numbers that are at the Midpoint, that is x.5, which means it doesn't do what you want it to. Also, the suggested solution works, but it's just a fancy if, so you have the same branch.

Comment: @William. Thanks, maybe that's why answerer deleted it.